# Radius of convergence of a "subseries" of a series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

When I was solving an exercise related to power series with complex numbers, I had the next question. I thought that was trivial, but, in fact, it isn't.

Let $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nz^n$ a power series (centered at 0), where for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $a_n\in\mathbb{C}$, such that the series converges if and only if $|z|<R$, i.e., $R$ is the radius of convergence of the series. If we take $\{a_{n_k}\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a subsequence of $\{a_n\}$ then, what can we say about the radius  of convergence $r$ of the series $\displaystyle\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}^{} a_{n_k}z^{n_k}$? Is $r$ related to $R$?

My first approach was thought that the radius was the same, but, it isn't true. Moreover, maybe the series doesn't converges for a certain values. Now I don't know how to proceed. Any hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The radius of convergence $R$ for the power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n z^n$ is given by 
$$
R=\frac1{\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} |a_n|^{\frac1n}}.
$$
For the power series with a subsequence $a_{n_k}$, we have 
$$
r=\frac1{\limsup_{k\rightarrow\infty} |a_{n_k}|^{\frac1{n_k}}}.
$$
So, we see that $R\leq r$.

Here is an example that the inequality can be strict.

$a_n = \begin{cases} 2^n \ \mbox{ if $n$ is even}\\ 2^{-n} \ \mbox{ if $n$ is odd}\end{cases}$.

Then $R=1/2$ but for the subsequence of all odd numbers, we have $r=2$.

Answer (score 2):

The radius of convergence $\sum a_nz^n$ is

$$R = \frac{1}{\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}}$$

Remember the $\limsup$ of a sequence is its greatest accumulation point.
Your new sequence is like the old one, except a bunch of terms are replaced by $0$s.
This might mean the greatest accumulation point of your new sequence is *less* than the old one, but of course it can't be greater.

Which in turn implies that your new radius is $\geq R$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not such an expert in Complex Analysis, but I guess you can't say much just for choosing indexes (finitely ou infinitely) without knowing the series very well.

Think for a moment in a series which terms even indexes are null. You can choose only the odd indexes and the radius of convergence doesn't change at all.

Think again for a moment in an alternate series. Deleting some indexes can make the series diverge with that radius of convergence.

Now, about an absolutely convergent series with only non-zero terms... that may be a good question.